# Python pandas - multiple columns to one series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have an excel spreadsheet with raw data in:
demo-data:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |

How do I combine all the numbers to one series, so I can start doing math on it. They are all just numbers of the same "kind"

Comment: What exactly you want to do with the given column.?

Answer (score 0):

Given your dataframe as `df`, this function may help `df.values.flatten()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your dataframe to a list and iterate through it to extract and put values into a 1D list:

```
df = pd.read_excel("data.xls")
lst = df.to_numpy().tolist()
result = []
for row in lst:
    for item in row:
        result.append(item)
```